# Jest and Create-react-app: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, babeljs

I have a React Native application where I have some files with some methods that calls certain endpoints. When I try to run `Jest` is throwing me an error at a local file that is imported.
[image]

I have the next `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "appName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "some description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.2",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "automock": false,
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest.setup.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

And the `jest.setup.js` file is the following:

```
import mockRNCNetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo/jest/netinfo-mock.js'

jest.mock('@react-native-community/netinfo', () => mockRNCNetInfo)
```

For the moment, this content is commented, otherwise will throw the same error like in the picture.

I tried to test the same stuff in another project where this `@react-native-community/netinfo` package wasn't saved in `devDependencies` but in `dependencies` and it worked but I am not sure if this is the problem. In this specific project I can't let this `package` as a `dependency`, it should be in `devDependencies`.

I found a lot of issues on this but none of them worked on this case, I don't know what to do anymore. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Just an idea, I've seen over the years that if you don't have all the parentheses, brackets closed as expected in your file and run the test, the same error will be thrown. So also pay attention to this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this answer on internet and it worked for me with some small add-ons but I will post it here maybe will help someone in future:

1. install `babel-jest`, `babel-preset-env`, `@babel/runtime` and `react` (the last one might be possible to be necessary only if some other package requires it)
2. create `.babelrc` file in `root directory` and add:

> ```
>   {
>      "env": {
>       "test": {
>         "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
>       }
>     }
>   }
> ```

3. Run your code and should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/241#issuecomment-387584632

in `config-overrides.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  jest: (config) => {
    config.transformIgnorePatterns = ["/node_modules/(?!(@my-company))/"]
    return config;
  }
}
```